# vuejs got syntaxError when production buid

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm developing Vuejs project with Vuetify UI framework.

[image]

After I run `npm run build` on the server (AWS), I got `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token` and the project show white screen.

[image]

Then I try to do `npm run build` on my laptop, but everything work fine.

I would like to know this error cause of the server environment? or any issue. And how to fix it?

Regards.

Comment: Using S3 or Cloudfront? Do you have any routing configurations or something else that rewrites request URLs?

Comment: No, I dont use S3 or cloudfront. Only ubuntu with nginx install on the server. Do you know how to fix the rewrites?

Comment: Ah right, it's EC2 / ECS. What does your `try_files` configuration look like in NGINX?

Comment: only  location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your server is serving some HTML page in place of your JavaScript files. Open one of the .js files that the errors are coming from and look at its contents. It's probably a 404 page being incorrectly served with a 200 status, or something equivalent to that.

Comment: yes, it's 404 error. this because of rewrite configuration?